# Decomposition of a Pauli Gate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, linear-algebra

I want to know how to perform a Pauli gate spectral decomposition.

For example: $\sigma_x = \left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\1&0\end{matrix}\right)$

How is it spectral decomposition performed?

Sorry, I'm new in this Quantum Info Science... Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard linear algebra problem, and guaranteed to have a solution (*i.e.* you don't need to resort to a Jordan normal form) since $\sigma_x$ is Hermitian - you know that it can be diagonalized by a unitary matrix.

Write down the characteristic equation, solve for the eigenvalues, put the eigenvalues back into the equation $\sigma_x\, X=\lambda \,X$, solve for $X$ (you get a ray, *i.e.* a set of solutions each scale multiples of one another), normalize the $X$s, write the two normalized $X$s as columns of  a matrix (call it $P$) then the decomposition is $P\,\Lambda\, P^{-1}$